# how to get the maximum value from a specific portion of a array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max

I have a specific scenario that I need to scan a specific portion of an array for a maximum value of that portion and return the position of that value with regards to the entire array.
for example

```
 searchArray = [10,20,30,40,50,60,100,80,90,110]
```

I want to scan for the max value in portion 3 to 8, (40,50,60,100,80,90)

and then return the location of that value.

so in  this case max value is 100 and location is 6

is there a way to get that using python alone or with help oy numpy

Comment: position = searchArray.index(max(ary[3:8])) here 3 is the lower bound and 8 is the upper bound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First slice your list and then use index on the max function:

```
searchArray = [10,20,30,40,50,60,100,80,90,110]
slicedArray = searchArray[3:9]
print slicedArray.index(max(slicedArray))+3
```

This returns the index of the sliced array, plus the added beginSlice

Comment: This doesn't provide the correct index value. It should be the index within the original list

Comment: I said that in the last line, but  I changed the code now

Comment: No problem! If you could accept the answer that would be perfect

Comment: but what about print ` print searchArray.index(max(slicedArray)) . this works fine as well isnt it

Comment: First calling `max` which iterates through the whole list to find the highest value and then calling `index` which iterates through half the list *again* to find where that element was is redundant and should be avoided if performance matters. Check out my answer using an `enumerate` generator to get the indexes before searching the max value and avoid an unnecessary second iteration over the list.

Comment: If `max(slicedArray)` is in `searchArray[:3]` the returned index is not between 3 and 8.

Comment: You are correct, I will change it back to the original suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Try this...Assuming you want the index of the max in the whole list -

```
import numpy as np

searchArray = [10,20,30,40,50,60,100,80,90,110]

start_index = 3
end_index = 8

print (np.argmax(searchArray[start_index:end_index+1]) + start_index)
```

Comment: this is the only acceptable answer to this question

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn Why would you think so? Numpy is not even notably faster on really huge lists, so what is the advantage of this solution over the others in your opinion? Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate` to get an enumerated list of tuples (actually it's a generator, which means that it always only needs memory for one single entry and not for the whole list) holding the indexes and values, then use `max` with a custom comparator function to find the greatest value:

```
searchArray = [10,20,30,40,50,60,100,80,90,110]
lower_bound = 3  # the lower bound is inclusive, i.e. element 3 is the first checked one
upper_bound = 9  # the upper bound is exclusive, i.e. element 8 (9-1) is the last checked one

max_index, max_value = max(enumerate(searchArray[lower_bound:upper_bound], lower_bound),
                           key=lambda x: x[1])

print max_index, max_value
# output: 6 100
```

[See this code running on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/ItqRT8)

Comment: Thanks a lot. but using slicer is effective on this case i think

Comment: @D_Wills This approach uses slicing as well (`[lower_bound:upper_bound]`) - it just avoids searching the list again for the item returned by `max` just to find out its index. Instead I generate tuples of index and value on the fly using `enumerate` and let `max` process them. That way it only performs one iteration and directly returns both the index and the value.

Comment: I think you mean `max` and greatest value.

Comment: I like the `enumerate(..., lower_bound)` as well as other subtle issues... best answer

Comment: @ByteCommander thanks a lot for that. but when u put the upper bound  = 9, then it should scan position 9 as well.  this code does not scan the last position. then the answer should be position 9 value 110

Comment: @D_Wills This is how slicing works, the lower bound is inclusive, the upper bound is exclusive. If you don't want to set `upper_bound` to be the index of first item that should *not* be included *anymore*, you can also add this +1 directly into the slice where it's used: `... searchArray[lower_bound:upper_bound+1] ...`

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm open for critique and improvement suggestions, but I don't like downvotes without any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
sliced = searchArray[3:9]
m = max(sliced)
pos = sliced.index(m) + 3
```

I've added an offset of `3` to the position to give you the true index in the unmodified list.

Answer (score 0):

With `itemgetter`:

```
pos = max(enumerate(searcharray[3:9], 3), key=itemgetter(1))[0]
```

Answer (score -3):

i guess this what you want

```
maxVal = max(searchArray[3:8]) // to get max element

position = searchArray.index(max(ary[3:8])) //to get the position of the index
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, they want the index